# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_nlist"

Tags: ios, c, xcode, ios-simulator, x86-64

In adding 64 bits support to some iOS code I maintain, I found that the [nlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/nlist.3.html) function is not available for the x86_64 architecture (64 bits iOS simulator). Code invoking nlist() works fine for all other archs (armv7, armv7s, arm64 and i386) but will not build successfully for x86_64, where the linker fails to find the symbol in the linked libraries.

It can be reproduced on a template project created with Xcode, by simply adding:

```
#import <mach-o/nlist.h>

int testnlist()
{
    struct nlist nl[2];
    bzero(&nl, sizeof(struct nlist) * 2);
    return nlist("test", nl);
}
```

Results in:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_nlist", referenced from:
>          _testnlist in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tested on Xcode 6.1.1 with iOS SDK: 8.1, building for iPhone 6 simulator.

Looks to me like Apple might have forgotten to include some of the simulator's shared libraries built for x86_64, but I might also be overlooking something stupidly obvious...

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you tried `nlist_64`?

Comment: Nope, I haven't (I wasn't really aware of its existence either) but I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: Ah, I see. `nlist_64` is the symbol table entry structure for 64-bit, but the function nlist() is still missing anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, too. I don't have a solution for the function, I just wanted to know if the 64-bit version of the struct was available to you since that might hint at how things are missing. I'm not sure where to go from there, but it does sound like Apple neglected to include a 64-bit version of this utility.

Answer (score 0):

```
you might want to try:

#ifndef N_NLIST_DECLARED
struct nlist 
{
    union 
    {
        char *n_name;
        struct nlist *n_next;
        long n_strx;
    } n_un;
    unsigned char n_type;
    char n_other;
    short n_desc;
    unsigned long n_value;
};
#endif

which I extracted from:
<https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/android-4.1.2_r2/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux/4.6.x-google/include-fixed/linux/a.out.h>

in that same header file, you will find lots of other things that 
will be 'gotcha's when moving to 64bit code
```

Comment: This won't help, it's the implementation of the function nlist() that is missing, not the struct with the same name.